# How to update UI using angularJs when scope value changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.setMonth = function(month){
    $scope.month = month;
    alert($scope.month);
    $scope.getMonthData();
};

$scope.getMonthData = function(month){
    // getting data for all schedules which a user can book
    $http.get('http://localhost/cakephp/Schedules/allSchedulesWithoutConflict').success(function(data) {
        $scope.allSchedules = data;
        var array1 = [];
        var date = 1;
        $scope.array2 = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.allSchedules, function(item){
            array1 = item.Schedule.start_time.split('-');
            date = array1[1];
            console.log(date);
            if(date == $scope.month){
                $scope.array2.push(item);
            }
        })
        console.log($scope.array2);
    });
};
```

This is my angularJs code what is happening here is that this setMonth() function is get called from the html to change the $scope.month value and by using this month value i'm filtering data in the getMonthData() function which changes array2 value, i want this change in value to get reflected on the UI

This is my html code:

```html
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet">



  <!-- <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>-->
  <title>Book My Class</title>
  <?php
  // echo $this->Html->css('select.min');
  // echo $this->Html->css('fullcalendar.print');
  // echo $this->Html->css('fullcalendar');
  // echo $this->Html->css('tableheader');
  // echo $this->Html->css('pendingFeeButton');
  echo $this->Html->css('table');



  echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
  // echo $this->Html->css('font-awesome.min');
  echo $this->Html->script('/libraries/moment.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/jquery.min.js');
  echo $this->Html->script('/libraries/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');

  echo $this->Html->script('/libraries/angular.js');
  echo $this->Html->script('/libraries/angular-sanitize.js');
  echo $this->Html->script('/libraries/angular-ui-router.min.js');
  echo $this->Html->script('/libraries/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js');
  echo $this->Html->script('/libraries/lodash.min.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/app.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/utils/select.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/schedule.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/module.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/venue.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/user.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/holiday.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/autoschedule.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/modulecycle.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/moment.min.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/fullcalendar.min.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('/app/pendingfee.js');
  echo $this->Html->script('/StudentView/table.js');

  // echo $this->Html->script('/StudentView/classData.js');




  // echo $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-message.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-material.js');
  // echo $this->Html->script('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js');

  ?>

 </head>
 <body ng-app= 'myapp'>
  <div class="page-container">

   <!-- top navbar -->
   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <h class="pull-left"><b>Alchemist Scheduler</b></h>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"><a href="/cakephp-2.8.2/users/logout" ng-click="logout" class="navbar-link navbar-right">LOGOUT</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="container" style="margin-top:40px">

    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

     <!-- sidebar -->
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Dash Board</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Book Classes</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Attendance</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Mentor</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
      </ul>

     </div>

     <div ng-controller="twoWeekClassCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="data in classData track by $index">
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default" >
         <div class="panel-heading">{{data.Schedule.start_time}}</div>
         <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
           <li>{{data.Schedule.name}}</li>
           <li ng-if='data.C[0].faculty_name = null'>{{data.C[0].faculty_name}}</li>
           <li ng-if='data.C[0].venue != null'>{{data.C[0].venue}}</li>
          </ul>
          <div ng-if="data.C" ng-repeat="class in data.C" style="display : inline" >
           <i ng-if='data.Attendance[$index].is_present == false'class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" style='color:red'></i>
           <i ng-if='data.Attendance[$index].is_present == true'class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" style='color:green'></i>
           <i ng-if='data.Attendance[$index].is_present == null'class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
   </div><!--/.page-container-->




   <div class="text-center" ng-controller = 'twoWeekClassCtrl'>
    <ul class = "pagination pagination-lg">
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click= "">&laquo;</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(01)">January</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(02)">February</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(03)">March</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(04)">April</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(05)">May</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(06)">June</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(07)">July</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(08)">August</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(09)">September</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(10)">Ocober</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(11)">November</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="getMonthData(12)">December</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#" ng-click="" >&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>

   </div>
   <table class="table table-striped" ng-controller = 'twoWeekClassCtrl'>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th> <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Schedule.name'">
       Module
       <span ng-show="sortType == 'Schedule.name'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      </a></th>

      <th><a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Schedule.reg_start_date'">
       Start Date
       <span ng-show="sortType == 'Schedule.reg_start_date'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      </a></th>

      <th>Reg Ends</th>

      <th> <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'">
       Venue
       <span ng-show="sortType == 'name'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      </a></th>

      <th> <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'">
       Faculty
       <span ng-show="sortType == 'name'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      </a></th>

      <th> <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'">
       Book
       <span ng-show="sortType == 'name'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      </a></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
     <tr ng-repeat="data in array2  | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse" >
      <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.Schedule.name}} {{data.Schedule.start_time}}</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.Schedule.reg_start_date}}</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.Schedule.reg_end_date}}</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.C[0].faculty_name}}</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">{{data.C[0].venue}}</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell"> <button  ng-if="data.Schedule.purpose == 'book'" type="button" ng-click="book(data.Schedule.id);row.selected=!row.selected" class="pull-right btn btn-xs">
       <span ng-class=""></span>
       {{row.selected?'Cancel':'Book'}}
      </button>
      <button  ng-if="data.Schedule.purpose == 'cancel'" type="button" ng-click="book(data.Schedule.id);row.selected=!row.selected" class="pull-right btn btn-xs">
       <span ng-class=""></span>
       {{row.selected?'Book':'Cancel'}}
      </button>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>


  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

output of console.log(jsonStringify(array2):

[{"Schedule":{"id":"574","created":"2015-11-17 22:00:35","modified":"2015-11-17 22:01:45","reg_start_date":"2015-11-17","reg_end_date":"2015-12-17","start_time":"2015-12-20 09:00:00","end_time":"2016-01-10 11:00:00","reg_type_id":"1","schedule_state_id":"4","error_count":"0","is_forced":null,"capacity":"25","default_backup_day":null,"default_backup_time":null,"filter_reg":null,"c_count":"4","min_batch":"15","module_id":"9","name":"DI-Logical Reasoning","description":"","reg_start_days":"33","reg_end_days":"3","instructions":"","draft_count":"0","cancel_count":"0","auto_schedule_id":null,"registration_count":"16","purpose":"book"},"C":

Comment: What's the output of `console.log($scope.array2);`?

Comment: @JohnSmith i have edited the code, you can now see the output.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.array2));`?

Comment: edited the code @2ps

Comment: Can you please post your full html template?

Comment: @Saad did what you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ng-controller` multiple times in the template. When the template loads and angular finds `ng-controller`, the controller `twoWeekClassCtrl` loads again with a new `$scope` for each `ng-controller`. So, three `$scope` gets created and each are different from the other. And, that's why your view didn't get updated.

To solve this, you need to use one `ng-controller`. Place that `ng-controller` at the template just after body tag so that `twoWeekClassCtrl` loads once and only one scope gets created. Like this:

```
<body ng-app= 'myapp'>
    <div class="page-container" ng-controller="twoWeekClassCtrl">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </div>
 </body>
```

Remove ng-controller from all other three divs.

Comment: Thank you very much it solved the problem, that was a silly mistake from my side :P

Comment: @AnujMittal You're welcome. Silly mistake happens. Accept the answer so that other user can know the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

when the scope change to update the view try to add in your js after the scope was updated:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

If you see $digest already in progress it's to say that your scope is already in refreshing. You don't need to call the $apply function.

try calling your scope modification inside a $timeout (don't forget to import it in your controller) it will do a "safe" scope modification

```
$timeout(function() {
  // run your scope modification
})
```

Comment: yes it can occured because your scope refresh is in progress. try to do the $apply in a timeout

Comment: nothing happened, but this time there was no error.

Comment: ok maybe you can try the controller as method to write your code ?

you often have less issue of scope not updated.